# how to convert rows into columns in spark dataframe, scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, transpose

Is there any way to transpose dataframe rows into columns.
I have following structure as a input:

```
val inputDF = Seq(("pid1","enc1", "bat"),
                  ("pid1","enc2", ""),
                  ("pid1","enc3", ""),
                  ("pid3","enc1", "cat"),
                  ("pid3","enc2", "")
              ).toDF("MemberID", "EncounterID", "entry" )

inputDF.show:

+--------+-----------+-----+
|MemberID|EncounterID|entry|
+--------+-----------+-----+
|    pid1|       enc1|  bat|
|    pid1|       enc2|     |
|    pid1|       enc3|     |
|    pid3|       enc1|  cat|
|    pid3|       enc2|     |
+--------+-----------+-----+

expected result:

+--------+----------+----------+----------+-----+
|MemberID|Encounter1|Encounter2|Encounter3|entry|
+--------+----------+----------+----------+-----+
|    pid1|      enc1|      enc2|      enc3|  bat|
|    pid3|      enc1|      enc2|      null|  cat|
+--------+----------+----------+----------+-----+
```

Please suggest if there is any optimized direct API available for transposing rows into columns.
my input data size is quite huge, so actions like collect, I wont be able to perform as it would take all the data on driver.
I am using Spark 2.x

Comment: What if `entry` had values for all 3 `EncounterID`? Can there only be 3 `EncounterID`s ?

Comment: entry will have only one value. and yes EncounterID is fixed, there will be only 3 EncounterID.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the result you expect? All three Encounter columns always have the same value...

Comment: Encounter value will change.. I have given this value just for sample.

Comment: Still not sure what you are trying to do but I updated my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure that what you need is what you actually asked. Yet, just in case here is an idea:

```
val entries = inputDF.where('entry isNotNull)
    .where('entry !== "")
    .select("MemberID", "entry").distinct

val df = inputDF.groupBy("MemberID")
    .agg(collect_list("EncounterID") as "encounterList")
    .join(entries, Seq("MemberID"))
df.show
+--------+-------------------------+-----+
|MemberID|           encounterList |entry|
+--------+-------------------------+-----+
|    pid1|       [enc2, enc1, enc3]|  bat|
|    pid3|             [enc2, enc1]|  cat|
+--------+-------------------------+-----+
```

The order of the list is not deterministic but you may sort it and then extract new columns from it with `.withColumn("Encounter1", sort_array($"encounterList")(0))`...

**Other idea**

In case what you want is to put the value of entry in the corresponding "Encounter" column, you can use a pivot:

```
inputDF
    .groupBy("MemberID")
    .pivot("EncounterID", Seq("enc1", "enc2", "enc3"))
    .agg(first("entry")).show

+--------+----+----+----+
|MemberID|enc1|enc2|enc3|
+--------+----+----+----+
|    pid1| bat|    |    |
|    pid3| cat|    |    |
+--------+----+----+----+
```

Adding `Seq("enc1", "enc2", "enc3")` is optionnal but since you know the content of the column, it will speed up the computation.

Comment: Sorry, I wont be able to hard code the values, this will be depends what values are there in a column. and there is one more thing I missed to add.. if for particular memberID only 2 rows are availble then code should be able to mark 3rd column as null. .. I will update the question

Comment: The list of values in the pivot is optionnal. If not provided, spark will simply trigger a small job to retrieve them.