# how to convert rows into columns in spark dataframe using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, transpose

how to convert a dataframe as below?

a dataframe I have:

| GROUP | ITEM | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| group1 | item1 | 100 |
| group1 | item2 | 200 |
| group1 | item3 | 300 |
| group2 | item1 | 400 |
| group2 | item2 | 500 |

expected result

| GROUP | ITEM1 | ITEM2 | ITEM3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| group1 | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| group2 | 400 | 500 |  |

Comment: similar question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47991462/how-to-convert-rows-into-columns-in-spark-dataframe-scala

Answer (score 2):

You can use pivot

```scala
val pivotDF = df.groupBy("GROUP").pivot("ITEM").first("AMOUNT")
pivotDF.show()
```

You can read more about pivot here https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-apache-spark.html